# How to connect android IPTV set top box running Android 4.4 for USB debugging

Tags: android, google-tv, android-tv

I am developing an android IPTV application running on Android 4.4. Does anyone know how to connect set-top box for installing application for testing. The set-top box have a USB port to connect USB pen-drive.

Can we use that USB port for installing applications directly in STB. If yes then How ?

Please help me out with this if anyone worked on android set top box programming.

Comment: "I don't know how to connect set-top box for installing application for testing" -- contact the device manufacturer and ask them.

Comment: I am asking that if you have worked on IPTV then how you tested your application..

Comment: It may well be that you are supposed to use adb over TCP with this.  Depending on the hardware, the USB "A" port you describe might actually go to a dual role type transceiver, but without an OTG detect pin so you would probably need to mode-switch it in software.  I've seen a few Android devices where there was an option in the settings menu to do this, others where from a root shell you could poke something in sysfs to do it. And it requires an illegal-per-the-spec USB A-A cable. Since that isn't supposed to exist, ones you buy can turn out to be miswired - I ultimately abused a USB 3 cable.

Comment: @mVJ your question dont related to IPTV tag! please remove that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open command line;

`adb connect [Your device's IP address]`

Once you connect your device via adb tool, just run your code from Android Studio. Your target device should be listed under *Connected Devices*.

*Make sure*

- to add **ADB** to the **PATH** to be able to run **adb.exe** on **cmd** from any directory
- the system and target device are in the same network

Answer (score 1):

Turn on ADB Debugging

You must enable ADB on the  Fire TV device before you can connect to the device.

```
From the main (Launcher) screen, select Settings.
Select System > Developer Options.
Select ADB Debugging.
```

Get the IP Address

You need the IP address of your Fire TV device on your network to connect ADB to it.

```
From the main (Launcher) screen, select Settings.
Select System > About > Network. Make note of the IP address listed on this screen.
```

Connect ADB

To connect your development computer to a Fire TV device, use the following steps:

```
Open a command prompt or terminal window.
Change directory to your Android SDK platform-tools directory.
Run the following commands, where <ipaddress> is the IP address of the Fire TV device noted in the previous section.

adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb connect <ipaddress>

Note: On Mac OS X and Linux you may need to prepend ./ to these commands, like this:

./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
./adb connect <ipaddress>


If the connection was sucessful, ADB responds with the message:
connected to <ipaddress>:5555

Verify that the Fire TV device appears in the list of devices:

adb devices


ADB reponds responds with the message:

List of devices attached
<ipaddress>:5555  device
ex : adb connect 192.168.1.1:5555
```